# Can i combine many js javascript files in one file

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jquery fileupload plugin and it has 7-8 js files which it loads.
Now others developers are also working on site and sometime it cause confusion and difficult to find which js file is used where.

So i am thinking if i can combine 7 files in one file so that i can know that thats my file

Comment: yes you can.. simply copy paste all the code in one single js file

Comment: And minimize them while you are at it

Comment: @PeeHaa minification is not a good idea if the file will be worked on later. You can minify but you should keep the original.

Comment: @JanDvorak jquery plugin mostly don't need any work.

Comment: @PeeHaa true. But then again, jQuery plugins should be downloaded in their minified form.

Comment: @JanDvorak Not all plugins have a [minified download option](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/blob/master/js/jquery.fileupload.js). *disclaimer: don't know whether this is the plugin OP is talking about*

Comment: When i combine the all files then i get this error  `TypeError: e.widget.extend is not a function in jquery-ui.min.js` if i dont use the combined file then no error in firebug. Does it amtter in which order i combine the files

Answer (score 1):

Try this to compile your javascript file or code.

http://closure-compiler.appspot.com

Answer (score 0):

While possibly overkill in this particular case, it might be worth checking out [grunt](http://gruntjs.com). It will let you keep your files divided into multiple files for when you are working on them, and as soon as any file change compiling, minifying and combining them into a single/groups of files as desired, while also allowing you to define the load order of your code.

It requires some setup the first time you run it (which you can later use as a template) but greatly improves the process of combining/minifying files, and also has support for processing [coffescript](http://coffeescript.org) and [sass](http://sass-lang.com) among others, as well as writing unit tests for your code.

Answer (score 0):

I use [Rake](http://rake.rubyforge.org/) to compile Javascript (and SASS to CSS, as well). It minifies the files in a unique JS. It's written in Ruby, but it's easy to configure and it works very fine.

But if more developers are working on the same code, another good idea I strongly suggest is to to use a SVN (sub-version control system), as [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.net/) or [Git](http://git-scm.com/). This will allow many developers to work on the same source files, without losing any change.

Comment: Wow, how is source control software related to this question?!

Comment: @FlorianMargaine The user mentioned: "Now others developers are also working on site and sometime it cause confusion and difficult to find which js file is used where" ... therefore SVN is a good suggestion